# Wind force field not working

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

I am trying to get a waving effect for a flag in my animation I am working on. However when I click alt a the cloth fabric just hangs there not being affected at all by the wind. I have wind power at 163 and it is aimed right at the flag yet it still does not work. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27552 is the link to the file.

Comment: I too have this problem , Please help me out. I have attached blend file : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31250

Comment: Supplemental: Wind needs to be in the same layer with the cloth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly the  problem is but this is my guess.
You need to decrease the mass of the flag. By default it is quite heavy.

[image]

---

Final Result

http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=68256

Comment: Its set to the silk preset with a mass of .15

Comment: Ive tested it in new windows and it works just fine but for some reason it does not work in this file I've created.

Comment: If you want to upload the blend file I can take a look at it,

Comment: yeh how do I upload the file to here?

Comment: use  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It uses models from differing downloads off blend swap as well as elements which I created.

Comment: It's up to you to upload the file.

Comment: I already did the link is in the question

Comment: OKay I see it. That's one large blend file. in the future use copy and paste to paste the needed elements in their own blend file. This will keep the file size smaller.

Comment: oh ok didn't know I could do that awesome thank you. I had just appended them since thats what I had learned in a tutorial.

Comment: The meshes are too heavy for the wind to pick them up, I would decrease the mass and increase the strength of the wind.

Comment: I turned the masses down to .1 each and the wind up to 500 and still nothing could it be something with the settings?

Comment: wind to 1200, mass to 0.05

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, and my flag started to react to the wind force once I scaled it up 10 times.

The bigger the flag was (in Blender Units) the more it reacted to the wind force.

Check your scale!

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the cloth seems to need to "drop" completely before it will be affected by the wind. I tried a plane hanging from the top edge and because it was already in the "dropped" position it animated straight away with a wind force of 2000 to 9000 it flapped nicely, 10000 made it go nuts. I tried with a cloak next, much more complex, and after pinning it, it took 100 frames before I got some ripples with a wind force of 9000

Answer (score 2):

Also check **Falloff power**
(my problem was: too low `strength` and too big `falloff power`).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Scene size matters. If your clothes don't react to forces: go to the scene properties tab and scale up the Units. After you did it go to your cloth physics properties and you'll notice that the vertex mass has changed. Decrease the vertex mass and start the simulation

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else runs into a similar issue and comes across this thread, also please remember to make sure the *Force Field* is on the same layer as the cloth.

Answer (score 0):

Just play with the strength, the higher the better, mine touched >900000, strange but feels awesome afterwards.